# How to initialize one list of class values to another class list object in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to get the list of some `First` class which is already queried in DAL so I want to put it in some another list of `Second` class object in the business logic side.

I tried like below

```
List<Second> HitoryList = new List<Second>();

//getting list of data from DAL
var Hitory = _objHitoryDB.GetHitoryId(Id);

HitoryList = ((List<First>)Hitory.Select(
                                        x => new Second()
                                        {
                                            imID = x.imID,
                                            Title = x.Title,
                                            Desc = x.Desc,
                                            CreatedOn= x.CreatedOn
                                        }
                                    ).ToList();
```

Actually, I need to return to ActionResult return some more list of 'Second' class type of data, so I created 'Second' type List array.

```
IEnumerable<Second>[] Details = new IEnumerable<Second>[4];
```

in two 0 and 1 array of lists initialize the same type i.e, 'Second class type list,

```
   Details[0] = PersonalInfo;
   Details[1] = OffcInfo;
```

but in a 3rd and 4th array of the list need to initialize the different class types.
so, How to initialize one list of class values to another class list object in MVC controller?

Comment: Why you tag Angular JS here.

Comment: because iam returning to angular js from controller i.e ActionResult methode.

Comment: But your problem is related to MVC not Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I get it right, that your question is: How to map `List<First>` to `List<Second>`? If not, leave comment and I'll fix answer

You were in good path in your first code snippet. Here is fixed and commented version::

```
//getting list of data from DAL, result is IEnumerable<First> or similar (List etc)
var Hitory = _objHitoryDB.GetHitoryId(Id);

//Declare List<Second> variable where we will store result of mapped data
List<Second> HitoryList = null;

//Map First-objects to Second objects with Linq Select: 
HitoryList = ((List<Second>)Hitory.Select(
    x => new Second()
    {
      imID = x.imID,
      Title = x.Title,
      Desc = x.Desc,
      CreatedOn= x.CreatedOn
    }).ToList();
```